# How to make redirect from signOut event in next-auth?

Tags: redirect, next.js, next-auth

I tried to make redirect inside signOut event, like this:

```
events: {
    signOut: async function ({ token }) {
      const logoutToken = token as unknown as any
      const tokenResponse = await fetch(
        `${process.env.NEXT_API_URL}/auth/logout`,
        {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Cookie': cookieList(logoutToken),
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${logoutToken.accessToken}`,
          },
        },
      );
        const json = await tokenResponse.json()
        redirect(json)
    },
  },
```

, but I received message: 'NEXT_REDIRECT. I could not find, how to make it possible. Inside json, there is url, that I need to redirect to.

Comment: If it is inside a json, it should probably be `redirect(json.url)` or whatever the key to the URL is.

Comment: The problem is not with that. It throws error even if I do redirect('/').